# how to minimize the output value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

hi m showing some value in jquery and just wants to reduce it,

value showing:

```
  6.333333333333333
```

I just wants that it shows like this:

```
  6.3
```

how to do this because google is not showing more results about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `round` method:

```js
var myNum = 6.333333333333333;
var rounded = Math.round( myNum * 10 ) / 10;
console.log(rounded);
```

Comment: or `Number(number.toFixed(1))` - the `Number()` being optional if you want the result to be a Number rather than a string

Comment: now nthing is showing maybe mistake in code:  {
                sortable: false,
                data:  function (data) {  
                    var rounded = Math.round( number * 10 ) / 10;                    // code to show ang rating at tab 4
                    return data.avgRating;
                }
            },

Comment: did you replaced `number` with your original variable ?

Comment: I replaced but nthing is happening

Comment: {
                sortable: false,
                data:  function (data) {  
                    var rounded = Math.round( data.avgRating * 10 ) / 10;                    // code to show ang rating at tab 4
                    return data.avgRating;
                }
            },

Comment: data.avgRating = Math.round( data.avgRating * 10 ) / 10